# Excel cell value minus (cell value + cell value)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm putting together an equation, but it doesn't seem to come out right.

Here's an example:

```
B7 value is 153.02746
C6 value is 154.5
$A$5 value is 1
```

Here's the code I have so far:

```
(B7-C6+$A$5)/C6+$A$5*100
```

Here's how I thought the equation would work out: 153.02746 - 155.5 / 155.5 x 100

But it doesn't come out right.

Just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: What result are you getting? What do you expect the result to be? Could have something to do with location of (or lack of) parentheses.

Comment: The result I'm getting is 99.99694149, but what I'm trying to get is what percentage of 154.5 + 1 is 153.02746 - 154.5 + 1. In other words, I'm trying to get what percentage of C6+$A$5 is B7-C6+$A$5. Obviously it's going to be a small percentage and not 99.99 or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @ImaginaryHuman072889 in the comment section, parenthesis (or rather the lack of them) is the issue.

Here are some examples:

```
=(B7-C6+A1)/(C6+A1)
```

Evaluates to: `-0.47254000/155.5` which is `-0.003038842`

```
=(B7-C6+A1)/C6+A1
```

Evaluates to: `(-0.47254000)/C6+A1` which evaluates to: `-0.47254000/154,5+A1` which evaluates to: `0.99694...`

Another option would be:

```
=(B7-(C6+A1))/(C6+A1)
```

which evaluates to -0.0159.

Obviously the lesson here is that: `3-2+1` evaluates differently (answer = 2) to `3-(2+1)` which is zero.

---

So while the basic math would be:

```
Percentage = Part/Total
```

You will have to play around with the parenthesis because I can't tell if you meant to plus `A1` before or after the first deduction. The answer is either my first option included above or the third, but the one thing you don't have to do is do the `*100`. Just as per your latest question you can just format the cell to a percentage.

***Hint:*** Use the build-in `Evaluate formula` function to your advantages to step through your equations and see what they evaluate to step by step.

Comment: None of those seem to work out for me. If 153.02746 - 155.5 is -2.47254, I worked out that -2.47254 is -1.59005787781% of 155.5. So, that's the result I'm wanting to get, -1.59005787781%. The hard part is trying to add the $A$5 into the equation which makes 154.5 into 155.5. You said that you can't tell if I meant plus $A$5 before or after, I'm trying to make it do B7- C6+$A$5 (Meaning: 153.02746 - 155.5). Does that make sense?

Comment: @acmarston, my third option mentioned does exactly that (had a typo in the answer which is now corrected), just change A1 to your absolute A5 reference: `=(B7-(C6+$A$5))/(C6+$A$5)` will give you exactly that percentage ;)

Comment: That equation is giving me -0.015900579 and not -1.59005787781.

Comment: If you would have read through my answer you would have noticed that you have to format your cell to a percentage (just as per your last question). Don't alter values multiplying them times 100 if not needed. @acmarston